# How does a beneficiary receive benefits if an FDIC insured bank goes bankrupt?

Tags: banking, beneficiaries

I have three questions:

Generally, in the US, can a beneficiary receive the inherited benefits for a certificate of deposits (CD) in a single bank if an account holder (single) who purchased the CDs is still alive but the bank the account holder purchases the CD goes bankrupt?

Generally, in the US, if an account holder (single) has more than $250K (e.g., $300K) in CDs in a single bank and named one beneficiary but before the account holder passes away, the bank goes bankrupt, then how much maximum benefits can the account holder and the beneficiary receive?

Generally, in the US, if an account holder (single) has more than $250K (e.g., $300K) in CDs in a single bank and named one beneficiary but suddenly, the account holder passes away before the bank goes bankrupt, then how much maximum benefits can the beneficiary receive?

Thank you.

Comment: Question #1 baffles the heck out of me.

Comment: what i'm asking is can the beneficiary receive any benefits if the account holder is still alive but the bank goes bankrupt? Or the beneficiary can ONLY receive benefits ONLY if the account holder passes away?

Comment: Your question *still* baffles me.  When does a beneficiary ***ever*** get his/her money?  **When the owner dies**, of course.

Comment: So even if the bank goes bankrupt, as long as the owner is still alive, the beneficiary will not get any money and the maximum the owner will be reimbursed is $250K, correct?

Comment: The money goes to the account holder. The beneficiary is not the account holder I have no clue why you might think anything else would happen.

Comment: "as long as the owner is still alive, the beneficiary will not get any money".  I think you're trolling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once the owner dies, beneficiary becomes the new owner. The CD might have to go through probate; at the very least you must present evidence of the owner’s death.

Account owners (which includes beneficiaries when they become the owners) are only *guaranteed* $250k protection, but it’s standard practice that all depositors get all their money.

Note that SVB and Republic are still open.  The web sites are up, doors open and computers doing the things  computers do for banks.  The beneficiary might have to go through some extra red tape when the bank’s assets and customers are taken over by a new bank, but probably not.

Remember: **the FDIC exists**.

Comment: The FDIC have set a pretty solid precedent with the three largest bank failures in the US all depositors been fully protected. I doubt they'd be able to get away with only 250K from now on.

Comment: I think that could be merely an exception, if other FDIC insured banks fail, I would say it's still better to err on the side of caution that each account holder is entitled to a maximum of $250K?

Comment: Sure; the written guarantee is the one to rely on if you are concerned about it. Most folks managing that amount of ready cash know this and do what they feel is appropriate.

Comment: $250k is the amount guaranteed. However, SVB has huge amounts of money, for example $90bn in treasury bonds. Those $90bn alone are enough to pay for more than 40% of the deposits, and they have much more money (just not readily available). So whatever FDIC does, people will get much more than $250k.

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld You "think that could be merely an exception".  Sure, it might be.  That's why the standard recommendation for *individuals* with more than $250K *in the bank* is to spread it around.  Not that many people have that much money in banks.